# Does drinking water from stainless steel increase hemoglobin?

Tags: hematology

I'm pretty sure iron molecules will be present in water.

[Cooks who use iron or stainless steel pots increase the amount of iron they consume](http://www.chiro.org/nutrition/FULL/Iron_Too_Much_of_a_Good_Thing.shtml)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is found in the article cited.

Comment: The article which you cite (which seems accurate and informative) already contains your answer, with a citation for further reading: "**Cooks who use iron or stainless steel pots** increase the amount of iron they consume. [22]" Iron-deficiency anemia was less common when people used cast-iron cookware. Steel releases much less iron. But **food** itself  remains by far the major source.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but [this study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/19335940/) examined the effect of cooking in stainless steel and found that it did not alleviate iron deficiency. I imagine that simply drinking water from a stainless steel container would be even less effective. Also I think this is an interesting question.